# DataSet stored procedure table names

Tags: stored-procedures, dataset, tablename

I am calling a stored procedure to return two tables. I am getting it as a dataset in my console application. The table names in the dataset are something like TABLE,TABLE1.

Is there anyway to change this to a meaningful names from stored procedure?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Typo mistake, Store_Procedure >> StoredProcedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can name DataTables from stored procedures.

Of course it's easy to do this in code.  In C# you can do the following, assuming a DataSet dataSet with two DataTables, one named TABLE and the other named TABLE1:

```
 dataSet.Tables["TABLE"].TableName = "MyBetterTableName";
 dataSet.Tables["TABLE1"].TableName = "AnotherTableName";
```

and while you're at it, you can name your DataSet:

```
 dataSet.DataSetName = "MyDataSet";
```

Answer (score 0):

**IMO** there is ZERO advantage of renaming unless we **know** we're getting the correct table reference.

The *actual* need is to know your tables by STRONG-NAMES controlled at the data source.... something to tie a SPECIFIC RESULT table to a NAME controlled by the SOURCE of the data-set.

There is ZERO difference in accessing "Table1" or "AnotherTableName" if the underlying table position has changed; it will still be wrong.  If the SPROC returns dynamic results-sets, the position is unpredictable.  If the SPROC is changed, even correctly, but positions change, you have a broken system.

I believe that is the root of this question.

And I think I have a very workable solution. check out [**this answe**r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930791/populate-dataset-with-table-names-from-stored-procedure/43507272#43507272).

*too long to reproduce here*